# Скролл div'а для чата

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, чат

Доброго времени суток!

Помогите пожалуйста, имеется блок где отображаются сообщения диалога, хочу сразу подчеркнуть:

1. В чате присутствует подгрузка старых сообщений, если подняться почти до края блока DIV (за 800px до края)
2. В этой страничке подключен WebSocket с сервером, если собеседник напишет сообщение, то оно тут де отобразится снизу блока (все прям как у обычных чат-приложений)

Это все у меня получилось сделать, но, к сожалению, столкнулся с неприятной проблемой:

Если я буду в самом низу блока, и собеседник напишет мне Сообщение, то scroll останется на своём месте, и приходится каждый раз вручную докручиватт до низа блока чтобы прочитать новое сообщение.

А так же, если у кого то из клиентов слабое интернет-соединение, то он может подняться до самого верха блока до того как контент отобразится (некое колличество старых сообщений подгрузится с сервера), в таком случае - он (клиент) будет подниматься вместе с контентом, то есть -> при подгрузке контента, клиент будет всегда находится в верху блока, в самом верху.

Тут можете "пощупать":

```css
        #display__chat {
            width: 300px;
            height: 600px;
            overflow: auto;
            border: 2px solid #F00;
        }
        .buttons {
            width: 300px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .buttons > button {
            width: 120px;
            height: 75px;
        }
```

```html
<h1>CHAT:</h1>

<div id="display__chat">
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
    <p>Это сообщение чата</p>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
    <button id="newMessage">Новое сообщение</button>
    <button id="oldMessage">Старое сообщение</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var divChat = document.getElementById('display__chat');
    var newMessage = document.getElementById('newMessage');
    var oldMessage = document.getElementById('oldMessage');

    newMessage.onclick = function () {
        divChat.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>• Это новое сообщение от собеседника или от меня же</p>');
    }

    oldMessage.onclick = function () {
        divChat.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<p>- Старое сообщение, которое подгрущилось при скролле</p>');
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Перед добавлением проверяйте позицию скролла, если он в самом низу, тогда после добавления сообщения, нужно программно прокрутить до низа/нового сообщения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При получении нового сообщения, можно докрутить до низа

```
window.scrollTo({
    top: document.body.scrollHeight
    behavior: "smooth"
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, а возможно как то запретить подниматься до самого края, так скажем, не доходя до него за 2-4px ?

Comment: Можно, только это не существенная разница в 2-4px пикселя, поэтому не понимаю для чего это. Лучше всего вверху показывать символ загрузки контента

Comment: Дело в том, что при подгрузке старых сообщений если scroll будет на позиции " 0 " (то есть в самом верху), то при добавлении контента (старых сообщений чата, все равно клиент будет оставаться на позиции " 0 ", а если не доходя до вершины блока, то он останется где стоял

Comment: Не лучшая идея скролить при новом сообщении.. Ибо человек мог подняться выше и что-то читать и тут бац его скролит вниз..

Comment: Можно использовать тот же код, если пользователь был на позиции 0, то после получения новых сообщений и их отрисовки, вычесть высоту новых сообщений, чтобы оставить его на том же месте

Comment: Большое спасибо! Так и сделаю

Comment: @OliverPatterson В вопросе речь о том, как сделать скролл вниз, я ответил. В описанном вами случае действительно скролить вниз не лучшая идея, но можно сделать проверку, что если пользователь скролит на вверх, то просто показывать уведомление о новом сообщений, а не делать авто скролл вниз

Comment: @ArmenSaakyan Отметьте вопрос как решенный)